# How did PUSH / APNS works?

Tags: iphone, push, apple-push-notifications

I read a few tutorials / howtos about Apples Push Notifications, but there are a lot of information out there, so I wanna know if I understand everything correct.

Here is how I understand it:

- You need a certificate for Puhs, you can get it in the development center (found very good tutorials for it)
- You need a database in which the DeviceToken is stored. This you can set into the database from your application itself (found a tutorial for that I think)
- When a user should get a message (e.g. gets a Private Message or something like this) you must send a PHP Payload to the apple server.

Is that all? (I know its a much longer, I only wanna know if I understand everything right).

Must I do any other thing on the client side else then save the device token to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you pretty much have it there.  If looking at sending large volumes then make sure that you are not opening and closing the connection to the Apple APNS servers as they treat it as a DOS attack.

The payload is also not PHP but JSON.

Also make sure you read from the feedback service and deactivated device tokens and stop sending them messages.

Client side you also need to "decode/process" the payload in the various app delegate places.  Essentially it is a discretionary and you can send custom info as part of the APNS payload.

Comment: Any links or info to talk to APNS without open/closing connection?

Comment: http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/02/apple-push-notification-and-how-to-keep-connection-alive/